# PostgreSQL query to return 10 highest numbers in ASC order

Tags: sql, postgresql

I found an issue in my query:

```
SELECT * FROM stocks_historic
WHERE ticker = x
ORDER BY YEAR ASC
LIMIT 10
```

Current table is this one:

```
stocks_historic (
    historic_id SMALLSERIAL UNIQUE,
    ticker VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    year VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    eps NUMERIC(6,2) NOT NULL,
    operatingCashFlow NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    shares NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    cash NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    currentLiabilities NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    currentAssets NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    incomeBeforeTax NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    incomeTaxExpense NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    totalDebt NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    revenue NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    costOfGoodSold NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    operatingIncome NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    equity NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    capitalExpenditures NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    fcf NUMERIC(12,4) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ticker, year)
);
```

Expected result:

If I have 15 rows with the same ticker where year go from 2010 to 2025, I expect to get last 10 years in ASC order:

```
historic_id: 1,
year: 2015,
historic_id: 2,
year: 2016,
historic_id: 3,
year: 2017,
...
```

The result is that I get the first 10 numbers, but Since I want the highest 10, is not working.

I know I can achieve that changing ASC for DESC, but that would return me years in an undesired order. The frontend is expecting years in ASC order so I would have to change everything to fit it.

Is there any way to get those 10 rows ASC ordered?

Thanks, Ruben.

Comment: Please add sample data and epected result

Comment: You order by year ascending (`ORDER BY year ASC`). Thus you get the first years. If you order by year descending (`ORDER BY year DESC`), you'll get the last years. Does that already answer your question?

Comment: I mentioned it in  the answer. Frontend is expecting them in ASC order. So to fit it comming in reverse I would have to change how frontend works in many places. If there is a better solution that dont make me code differently all the application I would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Order the results *again* after retrieving the last 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the last 10 years you need `ORDER BY ... DESC`. If you want the results to be in ascending order, you'll have to reorder them, eg :

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM stocks_historic
      WHERE ticker = x
      ORDER BY YEAR DESC
      LIMIT 10) z
ORDER BY YEAR ASC
```

While it's possible to use other ranking functions to identify the last 10 rows, eg `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY YEAR DESC)` the generated execution plan will still have to order the data twice - once to get the ROW_NUMBER and once to reorder the results.

Comment: Thanks very much. That was my first logical approach but couldn't manage to Order by 2 times in a row. Didn't know you could do that.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, PostgreSQL requires an alias for the derived table (aka subquery).

Answer (score 1):

If you order by year ascending

```
ORDER BY year ASC
```

and then take the first ten rows, you get the first ten years, of course.

If you ordered by year descending

```
ORDER BY year DESC
```

you'd get the last years.

If you want the last ten years shown in ascending order, then get that result first, then sort again:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM stocks_historic
  WHERE ticker = x
  ORDER BY year DESC
  FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS
) last_ten_years
ORDER BY year ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a subquery for getting the data, and an outer query to order it:

```
select *
from
    (SELECT * 
    FROM stocks_historic
    WHERE ticker = x
    ORDER BY YEAR desc
    LIMIT 10) temp
order by year asc
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    SELECT * FROM stocks_historic
    WHERE ticker = x
    ORDER BY YEAR ASC
    fetch first 10 rows only
```

Comment: unfortunately same result :( I I expect to get from 2013 to 2022, but it returns first 10 years, from 2012 to 2021.

Comment: That's identical to the question's query. `FETCH FIRST` and `LIMIT` do the same job

Comment: I didn't know you updated your question. at first i don't understand what do you want so it makes me confuse. Sorry... I won't update my answer since they have answered your question.

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers). While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are. Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.